# 2-cells in xy-pic annoying problem

Tags: xy-pic

The following part of my code does not compile

```
\usepackage[all,2cell]{xy}
\begin{document}
\UseTwocells
\xymatrix
{     B &        {}   & {} &    C\llltwocell}
\end{document}
```

The funny thing is that:

```
\usepackage[all,2cell]{xy}
\begin{document}
\UseTwocells
\xymatrix
{     B &        {}   & {} &    C\lltwocell}
\end{document}
```

compile very well. As you can see the difference is the number of l-letters preceding "twocell" command Can you please tell me how can I fix it?

Comment: Why do you think that there's a command `\llltwocell`? Is it documented? Otherwise, attaching characters to commands may lead to unknown commands.

Comment: So there is no possibility of making long two cell, since there is no such command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question could have been clearer but comparing `\ltwocell` and `\lltwocell` I assume you want:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,2cell]{xy}
\begin{document}
\UseTwocells
\typeout{\meaning\ltwocell}
\typeout{\meaning\lltwocell}
\typeout{\meaning\llltwocell}

\makeatletter
\def\llltwocell{\supermorphism {\xy@ {start of 2-cell}{\begingroup }\twocell@ }[0,-3]{}}
\makeatother
\xymatrix
{     B &        {}   & {} &    C\llltwocell}
\end{document}
```

The three typeout produce:

```
macro:->\supermorphism {\xy@ {start of 2-cell}{\begingroup }\twocell@ }[0,-1]{}

macro:->\supermorphism {\xy@ {start of 2-cell}{\begingroup }\twocell@ }[0,-2]{}

undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution with `tikz-cd`. You can just adapt the `column sep` to your needs. If you want, you can specify the bending radius as I did in order to get both arcs two the same height.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \[
    \begin{tikzcd}
       B & C \ar[bend right, ""name=U]{l} \ar[bend left, ""{name=L, above}]{l}
       \ar[Rightarrow, from=L, to=U]
    \end{tikzcd}\vee
    \begin{tikzcd}[column sep=20ex]
    B & C \ar[bend right=14, ""name=U]{l} \ar[bend left=14, ""{name=L, above}]{l}
    \ar[Rightarrow, from=L, to=U]
    \end{tikzcd}
    \]  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I have an answer for this which stays within the xypic package and doesn't require to define any new commands.

I don't know the reason why `\llltwocell` is not allowed. What you have to use is the command `\xtwocell`

Although I am not aware of why the syntax is like it is, because I discovered it by long ago and possibly by trial and error, you can write:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,2cell]{xy}
\UseTwocells
\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix{
B&&&C\xtwocell[lll]{}{\alpha}
}
\]
\end{document}
```

So if you only want the cell and not the arrows you can write `\xtwocell[lll]{}<>{\alpha}` or `\xtwocell[lll]{}<\omit>{\alpha}` these have worked the same for me without any problem.

[image]